# Routing AWS/Route53 subdomain to ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I have a domain name registered with **AWS's Route53** and want to create a subdomain pointing to an EC2 instance in a way that's persistent after restarting the machine *(which happens frequently)*.

### Previous Setup:

- EC2 instance is linked to an static Elastic IP (e.g. `1.1.1.1`)
- `subdomain.example.com` is an `A` record pointing to `1.1.1.1`
- **Problem:** Running out of Elastic IP addresses (there's a limit of 10 ips per region).

### Current Setup:

- EC2 instance has an autogenerated Public IP and Public DNS (e.g. `2.2.2.2` and `ec2-2-2-2-2.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com`)
- `subdomain.example.com` is a `CNAME` record pointing to `ec2-2-2-2-2.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com`
- **Problem:** On restarting the machine, a new IP/DNS addresses are generated and the route is broken!

### Also tried:

- Creating an *Autoscaling Group* and adding the instance to it.
- Creating a load balancer for the autoscaling group.
- Routing `subdomain.example.com` to the load balancer as a `CNAME` ALIAS
- **Problem:** Complicated and hard to maintain.

### Desired Setup

- A **simple** way to link a subdomain to the instance directly without depleting EIPs or creating load balancers.

Comment: Would you prefer the solution to be simple to setup or simple to maintain?(IMHO, just creating a load balancer is both /there is no need for autoscaling group/, but it does add cost)

Comment: I think a load balancer should be a good compromise as it is easy to both setup and doesn't require maintenance as you and @reza-mousavi mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an Elastic Load Balancing( ELB) and add your instance to it.After adding your instance to ELB, you no longer required the Elastic IP address(Static IP Address).

Not needs to create any scale up/down groups(You can add yourself manually/Also you can create one if you need).Each time your instance restarted and acquire the new IP address, Your load balancer will automatically perform health checks on your EC2 instances and only route traffic to instances that pass the health check.

Finally, change your DNS to your ELB.

For more info read 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/userguide/what-is-load-balancing.html?icmpid=docs_elbv2_console

Answer (score 1):

The only AWS supported method is to use Elastic IP Addresses. You are allocated 5 EIP addresses per region, but this is a soft limit. You can request more. EIP addresses are free while attached to running EC2 instances.

[AWS Service Limit Increase](https://console.aws.amazon.com/support/home#/case/create?issueType=service-limit-increase&limitType=service-code-vpc)

[EDIT]

Another method that will work is to change the Route53 Resource Record for you subdomain to point to the new IP address when the EC2 instance starts. This can be done with scripting (Python, etc.) or via the CLI.

Here is an example that I use to change a RRS for failover when doing maintenance.

**CLI Command Line:**

```
aws --profile PROD route53 change-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id Z13KCDXXXXXXXX --change-batch file://update_mydomain.json
```

**The contents of update_mydomain.json**

```
{
    "Comment": "Update record to reflect new IP address of www.mydomain.com",
    "Changes": [
        {
            "Action": "UPSERT",
            "ResourceRecordSet": {
                "Name": "www.mydomain.com.",
                "Type": "A",
                "TTL": 300,
                "ResourceRecords": [
                    {
                        "Value": "NEW_IP_ADDRESS"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Modify domain name and the IP address and then run the CLI command (which I put in a batch script). You will also need the Hosted Zone ID for your Route53 record for the CLI command.

Comment: I think this would work if we're running a lot of these boxes without needing a load balancer set up for each of them.

Answer (score -1):

```
1) Create Elastic BeanStalk Application with Single Instance Environment
2) Point CNAME to url of Elastic BeanStalk.
```

Since EBs environment is single instance only, you won't need Auto Scaling Group of Load Balancer. EBs url should also not effect due to restarting of system.

[image]

Comment: Per AWS documentation: In a single-instance environment, the elasticbeanstalk.com subdomain resolves to an Elastic IP address attached to the instance running your application. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customdomains.html

Comment: Also, you cannot start and stop EB instances at will. Stop in EB means terminate.